# Azure Storage: How to generate a SAS connection string using .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

I'm currently generating SAS tokens using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount` class like so:

```
var cloudStorageAccount = // create a new CloudStorageAccount
var sharedAccessAccountPolicy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write,
    Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
    ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
};

var token = cloudStorageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessAccountPolicy);
```

However, this returns a token with a `?` in front and does not include the blob endpoint. I was looking at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string) and noticed a SAS looks like below:

```
BlobEndpoint=https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net;
SharedAccessSignature=sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&si=tutorial-policy-635959936145100803&sig=9aCzs76n0E7y5BpEi2GvsSv433BZa22leDOZXX%2BXXIU%3D
```

What's neat about this is that I can use it as a connection string to directly initialize a `BlockBlobClient`.

How can I generate my token in the above format? I can parse my own and remove the `?` and then add the `BlobEndpoint` and `SharedAccessSignature` keys, but this is manual work and may not function properly in the future. Is there an SDK method that creates a SAS in the format that's shown on Microsoft's documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using `WindowsAzure.Storage` library. This library is deprecated.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

The recommended library to use is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs (v12)

With the v12 library, I was able to get a `SASUri` for a particular `blob` and create a `BlobClient` using the `SASUri` to download that blob without a need for string formatting.

```
 BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient("storage account conn string", "container name", "blob name");
        BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder(BlobSasPermissions.Write | BlobSasPermissions.Read, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1))
        {
            BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
            BlobName = blobClient.Name
        };

        var sasuri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(blobSasBuilder);

        var blobClientWithSasUri = new BlobClient(sasuri);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"path to download"))
        {
            blobClientWithSasUri.DownloadTo(fileStream);
        }
```

Comment: This is generated on the server side and it looks like the Azure Functions v3 runtime still uses the deprecated library. I might need to pull in the nuget for v12, but this will increase my output DLL size and consequently cold start times. :|

Comment: Yikes! Just tried creating a Azure function v3 which is triggered by blob storage and indeed it is using an old one

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-sas-create-dotnet?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnetv11#create-an-account-sas) to create an account SAS. It returns the value of `SharedAccessSignature`.

And there is no SDK to get the SAS token format mentioned above, even the latest SDK(azure.storage.blobs 12.7.0). I tried [azure.storage.blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-sas-create-dotnet?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet#create-an-account-sas) and it returned the SharedAccessSignature without '?'. I'm afraid you need to format by yourself.

[image]

```
Console.WriteLine($"BlobEndpoint=https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net;SharedAccessSignature={sasToken}");
```

I don't understand why it needs to be changed to this format. If you just use sas token in the next step, the default result can work well.